# How to stop tracking file in Git BUT allow "ignorable" changes to it on local copy?

Tags: git

I need to have a file on my repository that other developers can modify on their local copy while having Git ignore those changes.

Can't use
`git rm --cached <file>`
because the file is removed from the remote, making the file unavailable for future clones/pulls.

Can't use `git update-index --assume-unchanged <file>` nor `git update-index --skip-worktree <file>` because technically the file is still being tracked since git spits out this error message on any work tree overriding operations (e.g. `git checkout` or `git merge`) if the developer modifies the file:

> "Please commit your changes or stash them before you switch branches.
> Aborting"

Can't add the file to `.gitignore` because it has been tracked already.

Is there any Git operation I can use to achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm curious, why is the file even in the repo? If everyone has their own customized copy of it, it's not really part of the codebase, but more like a config file, right? So why not put a template in the repo instead of the live copy? (To be clear, I'm still learning software development.)

Comment: @wjandrea Your sort of answer your own question. Correct, is a template config file where the dev can insert an API key for example, but we don't want that API being pushed to the repo.

Comment: Right, so why are you putting it in the repo instead of, say, the user's home folder?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to allow ignoreable changes to the file in the local copy.  The [Git FAQ](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#Documentation/gitfaq.txt-HowdoIignorechangestoatrackedfile) explains this thoroughly.

If you want to use a template file, don't name it the same thing as the file you want it to end up as.  Name it something different, then either copy it into place with a script or let the user copy it into the right place, and ignore the actual configuration file while tracking the template.

Comment: That's unfortunate. It makes sense why it doesn't work though. Thanks!